# NestJS query params array has a length limit?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-validator

I have an endpoint in my NestJS server that takes a DTO as a @Query params. This DTO has an array :

```
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsArray, IsOptional, IsString, IsNumber } from 'class-validator';

export class BasicFiltersDTO {

  @IsArray()
  @IsOptional()
  @IsNumber({}, { each: true })
  @Type(() => Number)
  labelIds?: Array<number>;
  
  ... other fields
}
```

I registered my validation pipe in my `main.ts`:

```
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }));
```

Everything worked fine until I tried to pass an array that is longer than 21 elements :
[image]

[image]

For some reasons NestJS is unable to parse it as an array of number and just puts a plain javascript object with keys being the indexes

The endpoint's url looks like this :
`http://localhost:3000/myEndpoint?labelIds[0]=217&labelIds[1]=216&labelIds[2]=214&labelIds[3]=215&labelIds[4]=213&labelIds[5]=212&labelIds[6]=208&labelIds[7]=211&labelIds[8]=207&labelIds[9]=204&labelIds[10]=200&labelIds[11]=203&labelIds[12]=199&labelIds[13]=196&labelIds[14]=192&labelIds[15]=195&labelIds[16]=191&labelIds[17]=190&labelIds[18]=186&labelIds[19]=187&labelIds[20]=182&labelIds[21]=183&labelIds[22]=179&labelIds[23]=176&labelIds[24]=175`

I have no idea what's going on here, why would it break at 22 elements and not before ?

Comment: Just implemented this locally and tested with `curl` and with `xh` as terminal HTTP request runners, both worked fine and brought out the full 25 entries. I did have to modify your query to not include the `[number]` as express parses that as an Object, not an array, but the amount was not a problem

Comment: Yes you are right seems like the problem was from my frontend. As you said, express parses my query as an object. What I did is using `qs.stringify(params, { arrayFormat : 'comma' })` on my axios and in nestjs I used a custom transformer to transform the string with a `value.split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that NestJS has transformed the array into an object when the list has more than 21 items. A workaround for this to use `Object.values(labelIds)` in the DTO, then it should work as normal.